# I don't get the meaning of the "most compelling imagery"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Efforts to model the appearance and dynamics of the real world have produced some of the most compelling imagery in computer graphics.

But I don't get what the "the most compelling imagery" means in this context?
Can someone explain the meaning of these words in more simple English?

Comment: ... have produced **images that demand attention** in computer graphics. Does that help? I would take it that the images are striking and very different from what you'd normally see.

Comment: Compelling - holds one's attention.

Comment: compelling=that draws your attention to something.

Comment: An approximate synonym would be **fascinating**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[compelling](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compelling)** (adj): *Evoking interest, attention, or admiration in a powerfully irresistible way.*

"Compelling imagery" is, therefore, computer graphics that evoke strong interest, attention, or admiration.